# Custom widget doesn't show in admin

Tags: magento-1, magento-1.5

I am learning Magento (1.5) and am trying to create a custom widget to use in static blocks.

I have created a module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Freedom_Slidingwidget>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Widget />
            </depends>
        </Freedom_Slidingwidget>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and added the following xml files
\app\code\local\Freedom\Slidingwidget\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Freedom_Slidingwidget>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Freedom_Slidingwidget>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <slidingwidget>
                <class>Freedom_Slidingwidget_Helper</class>
            </slidingwidget>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <slidingwidget>
                <class>Freedom_Slidingwidget_Block</class>
            </slidingwidget>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

\app\code\local\Freedom\Slidingwidget\etc\widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets>
    <catalog_sliding type="slidingwidget/sliding" translate="name description" module="slidingwidget">
        <name>Catalog Products List</name>
        <description>List of Products in Category</description>
        <parameters>
            <category_id translate="label">
                <visible>1</visible>
                <required>1</required>
                <label>Category</label>
                <type>label</type>
                <helper_block>
                    <type>adminhtml/catalog_category_widget_chooser</type>
                    <data>
                        <button translate="open">
                            <open>Select Category...</open>
                        </button>
                    </data>
                </helper_block>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            </category_id>
            <template translate="label">
                <required>1</required>
                <label>Template</label>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <type>select</type>
                <value>freedom/slidingwidget/widget/sliding_category_products.phtml</value>
                <values>
                    <default translate="label">
                        <value>freedom/catalogproducts/widget/sliding_category_products.phtml</value>
                        <label>Sliding Category Products</label>
                    </default>
                </values>
            </template>
        </parameters>
    </catalog_sliding>
</widgets>
```

As soon as I upload the widget.xml file all the widgets in admin dissapear, remove the file and all is ok.
I have been googling this for a couple of days now and judging by all I have read, this should be working.

I am also getting the following warnings in my system.log

```
Warning: include(Mage_Slidingwidget_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/freedoms/public_html/magento_1.5.1.0/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
Warning: include(Mage_Slidingwidget_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/freedoms/public_html/magento_1.5.1.0/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage_Slidingwidget_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/freedoms/public_html/magento_1.5.1.0/includes/src:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php55/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/freedoms/public_html/magento_1.5.1.0/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to see that you finally got it working. This answer helps you to resolve the final notice error that you are getting in `system.log`.

Create following helper class in your module.

File: `app\code\local\Freedom\Catalog\Helper\Data.php`

```
<?php
class Freedom_Catalog_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

### EDIT

Add your helper class accordingly. ie,

File: `app\code\local\Freedom\Slidingwidget\Helper\Data.php`

```
<?php
class Freedom_Slidingwidget_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Now the actual problem here now is, you are enabled your modules compilation and after the changes that you have made, you didn't recompile it.

So disable compilation (this is what the best recommendation) and clear all your cache. All errors will be gone.

Comment: I alredy have that thanks.  No output from widget though!!!

Comment: It's broken again.  There is already a catalog module that comes with Magento, I thought there might be a conflict so I changed my file and directory names and it broke. Removed my answer as it obviously ain't right and updated my question.

Comment: what is the error that you are now getting?

Comment: The errors from system.log are shown at the bottom of my post above along with my new xml files, thanks for looking

Comment: Sorry, just read your edit and it worked, many thanks.